# React Redux - using dispatch inside an onclick function throwing "Cannot update a component ..." error

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

In my simple React app, I was passing a state for whether the user is logged in from a parent component down through numerous children, so that the children could have logged in vs logged out logic. The `SignIn` component had the form to sign the user in, while the `Header` component contained a button that signed the user out. This was all working.

But, I learned about Redux and wanted to implement that to clean up my states. I started with this isLoggedIn state. I also have redux-toolkit going.

So now, I have a slice that looks like this:

```
const initialState: AuthState = {
    loggedIn: false,
    authedUser: null,
}

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        login: (state) => {
            state.loggedIn = true  // Mutable change should be OK with redux-toolkit
        },
        logout: (state) => {
            state.loggedIn = false
        },
...

export const { login, logout, ... } = authSlice.actions
```

In the `Header`, I have:

```
...
    let isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.loggedIn)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
...

    const handleLogOut = e => {
        console.log("Clicked log out");
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        // setLoggedIn(false); <- this used to be a state passed down from the parent, pre-Redux
        dispatch(logout());
        navigate("/");
    }

    return (
        ...
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={(e) => handleLogOut(e)}>
               Log out
            </Button>
        ...
    )
```

When I click the button, I get the error `Cannot update a component (Header) while rendering a different component (App).` I implemented very similar code on the signin side and am getting the same error there.

My assumption is that the error has something to do with having `dispatch` within a function that's triggered by a button click, but I can't tell what exactly is wrong.

One thing I've tried is moving the `dispatch` into a `useEffect`. To do that, I created the `useEffect` with the `dispatch` inside in the component's function declaration, and had it trigger on a local variable, `localIsLoggedIn`, which is initialized as true and the click function sets to false, for example. This didn't seem to work either - the `useEffect` never fired.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being nothing to do with where the `dispatch()` calls were. The problem was that in my App.js, I had logic to check the localStorage for an auth token; if the token was found, there would be a `dispatch(login)`, and if not, a `dispatch(logout)`. I'm guessing the problem was that when the `Header` sent its own `dispatch(logout)`, it caused some conflict when the components all re-rendered, leading to that error.

What I did to fix this was remove that auth check from App.js, and instead put it in my authSlice.ts file